# Why are multiple AJAX requests waiting (hanging) for 1s+ between them?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, debian, delay

Whenever I send more than 1 paralel ajax request at a time to my backend, some respond within a reasonable timeframe (<100ms), however some of the requests **hang for approximately 1s** (long TTFB) before returning a response, regardless of which order they are executed in.

I have decided to test this out by creating a very simple HTML+jQuery/PHP  (frontend+backend) script which creates 6 paralel ajax requests and running it both on my local server, as well as Digitalocean's server using the same setup (Debian 10 Apache + PHP 7.4).

**The results on local server:**

[image]

**The results on Digitalocean server:**

[image]

**The javascript:**

```
 function ajaxAtOnce() {
        $.get("ajax1.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        $.get("ajax2.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        $.get("ajax3.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        $.get("ajax4.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        $.get("ajax5.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        $.get("ajax6.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

**PHP endpoints (all equal):**

```
<?php

    // return 100 randomly ordered numbers
    $array = range(1,100);
    shuffle($array);
    echo json_encode($array);
```

**Important notes**

- If I hardcode a large enough **"timeout"** inbetween ajax requests, I get a response within expected timeframe:

```
function ajaxWithTimeout() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("ajax1.php", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("ajax2.php", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }, 2200);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("ajax3.php", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }, 3500);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("ajax4.php", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }, 4700);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("ajax5.php", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }, 5900);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("ajax6.php", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }, 7100);
    }
```

- If I send all the requests **to the same endpoint** (ajax1.php for example), there is no problem
- After some research I found 2 server parameters that seem to be mentioned with regards to this issue, but they are set to their default values, and removing the limit does not have an effect:

  **RateLimitInterval=30s, RateLimitBurst=1000**

As you can imagine, this issue can be very frustrating, especially when developing a SPA in a JS framework like React, which is where I first noticed the issue.

**Edits:**

- Local server is using CGI/FastCGI PHP

Comment: Do you run php in mod_php or CGI mode?

Comment: @Yatsenko CGI/FastCGI